# Timeout after callback

Tags: jquery, callback

I tried something simple; just call a function via callback. Before this function is executed I want a delay of 800ms - after this function is finished, the next one should be executed.

Therefore I tried many different ways, none worked. This is one of my attempts:

```
$( "#box" ).click(function() {      
    $( "#open" ).hide().setTimeout(function() {
        alert("TEST");
    }, 800);
})
```

What am I doing wrong?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$( "#box" ).click(function() {      
    $( "#open" ).hide(); // hides right away, no need for callback
    setTimeout(function() { // not chainable, but does wait 0.8 seconds
        alert("TEST");
    }, 800);
});
```

Comment: Thanks, may I ask one more question:

I want to set bottom of a DIV to 0 and afterwards the height of the same div also to 0. At the end the the div should get "display = none;"

How can I make the animations (bottom & height = 0) follow each other with the same speed, so that the movement is a smooth one, (the top line of the div should move always at the same speed) when I don't know the height of the DIV because it adapts to the height of it's content?
http://pastebin.com/3VYnYyYQ

Answer (score 0):

Use 'window.setInterval()', here are the docs: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/window.setInterval

```
$( "#box" ).click(function() {      
    $( "#open" ).hide();
    window.setInterval(function() {
        alert("TEST");
    }, 800);
})
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$( "#box" ).click(function() {      
  $( "#open" ).hide(1000, function() {
    alert("TEST");
   });
})
```